# How to create framework.odex in android

Tags: java, android, android-source, android-framework

I'm trying to make changes in Android OS so I downloaded AOSP, make some changes and build it.

Now I want to replace `framework.jar` and `framework2.jar` on my device (Nexus 5, 4.4.4) but I see that this is an "odex" device - Which means - I have also `framework.odex` and `frameork2.odex`.

Can someone help me and explain me how to create those 2 files? I Google it but found only how to odex apk and not framework.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try to flash images to device ? You need to build complete AOSP source code and flash device with below commands :

```
adb reboot bootloader

IMG_PATH="./out/target/product/grouper";

# Erase userdata
fastboot -w

echo Flashing System .. 
fastboot flash system $IMG_PATH/system.img
echo Flashig Boot ... 
fastboot flash boot $IMG_PATH/boot.img
echo Flashin Recovery .. 
fastboot flash recovery $IMG_PATH/recovery.img
echo now rebooting device ...
fastboot reboot
```

The way you are trying, framework.jar might be having different signature than system signature.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant documentation is here:

http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/dalvik/docs/dexopt.html

(Don't know how dated this is. You can find hosted versions of this doc by searching for "dexopt.html")

Basically, Android runs dex class files through an optimizer before it runs them. For applications, the optimization happens either at install time, or just-in-time. For framework code, it seems to happen at build time.

Just looking at the information presented there, it seems you can either:

- Run the AOSP build such that not just the framework.jar files are generated, but also the framework.odex files (similar to Harry's answer, but you may be able to extract just the odex files without creating an image)
- Trick the package manager into odexing your new framework code and grab the odexed files from the odex cache. Relevant code may be here: http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#1229